# Input Form OnChange Function Not Displaying Data?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, api, input

So I made this codepen here https://codepen.io/shodoro/pen/xxYqXqv?editors=1111

I am trying to get whatever I type into my input form to display in my console, but everytime I type something it just shows " "

Right now I understand that I set my data to be " ", but I don't know how to make what I type to display

heres the html

```
      <form>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Street" id="street" onchange="updateInfo()">
          <input type="text" placeholder="City" id="city" onchange="updateInfo()">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Zipcode" id="zipcode" onchange="updateInfo()">
      </form>
```

Here's the javascript

```
      function updateInfo() {
          const url = ""
          const data = {
              Street: '',
              City: '',
              Zipcode: '',
          }

          document.getElementById('street').value = data.Street

          console.log('hi', data.Street)
      }
```

Note eventually I will want to integrate this with a backend API, so whatever I type will update into the API data, but for now I just want to confirm my inputs work first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting the data you are typing as you are not looking for it.
Forms are submitted on button clicks unless the type of the form button is specifically not `submit` type. You need to prevent your form from submitting using the `preventDefault` method.

Add to that, you are assigning the empty field of the `Data` object into the input field's value. I think what you are trying to achieve is

```
data.Street = document.getElementById('street').value;
```

Comment: why did changing the order make it work?

Comment: Its not changing the order. It's simple assignment operator. You assign the value on the right to the variable on the left.

Comment: Ex: let k = 77; 
You are assigning 77 to the variable k and not the other way around

Comment: ah so would I put my updateInfo() function on the form submit in order to make it only display my data after I filled out all my other input fields? because right now if I click on my next input it ends up logging the data right away

Comment: What your code currently does is individually getting all the input fields' values. Actually, you are just using the `input#street`. I'd recommend you follow this sequence:
1. remove all the ID from the input fields
2. add ID to the form to detect the form from the DOM
3. use the form submission event to prevent the default submission behavior
4. using FormData constructor get the form data and then do the rest of your code.

Look up MDN docs for FormData and how to use it.

Comment: my end goal is to make all the form data get sent to a backend API where it gets stored, so with your method would that be the correct way? because I saw the code was like `<form action="url of api" method="post">...`

Comment: The above code interacts directly with the backend. The action attribute submits the form data to the backend API endpoint using the post method. It's the old way of doing and it works fine. However, if you are using a front end framework like react, vue, angular etc you'd want to prevent the form submission so that you can validate the formdata on the client side and then submit the validated data to the backend using AJAX calls (eg: fetch API)

Comment: so if I am just using regular html and JS, then a simple preventDefault() is sufficient in my JS function?

Comment: Yes. But you'd have to send the form data to the backend using AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
document.getElementById('street').value = data.Street
```

to

```
   data.Street = document.getElementById('street').value
```